# Set of rules for textual analysis - Natural language processing

Tags: nlp, sentiment-analysis

Does there exist a guide with a set of rules for *textual analysis* / *natural language processing*?

Do you have some specific developed package (e.g. in Python) for textual sentiment analysis?

Here is the application I am faced with:

Let's say **I have two dictionaries, A and B. A contains "negative" words, and B contains "positive" words.** What I can do is *count* the negative and the positive number of words.

This created some issues, such as the following: let's suppose that "`exceptionally`" is a `positive` word, and "`serious`" is a `negative` word.

If I have the two words following each other, I have `"exceptionally serious"`. In such a case, the two words cancel each other, which means I have 1 negative and 1 positive word. This is not true, because in reality it is a **double negative**.

So, my question is, is there a *set of rules* I can apply so that I improve my code, or is there some *software* that already takes into account such mechanisms, and applies *textual sentiment analysis*? Is there some implementation which I can feed the dictionaries and provide me with textual sentiment after it applies a *set of rules such as double negatives*?

Comment: it sounds like you are just looking for different dictionaries.

Comment: no I am looking for a way to take into account cases such as double negations and more sophisticated sentiment analysis techniques than just counting the number of positive and negative words

Comment: so have you just been using dictionaries so far? or have you tried anything else?

Comment: Yes just the dictionaries, this is what i am asking, how to improve the process, either by using these dictionaries along with some rules such as double negation, or using some other approach

Comment: basically, this is a classification task. So you could learn a model and then us this to classify your texts. Check out the following link: http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/

Answer (score 2):

We did sentiment analysis at San Diego State using nltk with python. Really fun and easy! http://text-processing.com/demo/sentiment/ for an example I entered "exceptionally serious" and it knows that it is NEG.

easy enough example to follow: http://www.laurentluce.com/posts/twitter-sentiment-analysis-using-python-and-nltk/

Comment: I will check this out but I put an article which was obviously negative and it said it was neutral.. I will check it out more and come back with feedback

Comment: I tried it, it works for small sentences such as "exceptionally serious" but fails quite miserably if the text is larger (I gave as input an article which was clearly negative, and it said it was neutral). Plus I need a tool which gives me an actual sentiment value, instead of saying whether the article is negative, positive, or neutral